# NoClassDefFoundError in Java Servlets not duplicate

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jar, noclassdeffounderror

The answers do not solve my porblem. Both the duplicates that have been marked, have been tried. They don't work.

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong with this?

StackTrace on Server Logs:

```
May 26, 2016 3:23:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [createFLSfromXML] in context with path [/JuzzyOnline] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: type1/system/T1_Rulebase
    at org.juzzy.server.ProcessInputs.<init>(ProcessInputs.java:26)
    at org.juzzy.server.CreateFLS.doGet(CreateFLS.java:28)
    at org.juzzy.server.CreateFLS.doPost(CreateFLS.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

StackTrace on WebBrowser:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: type1/system/T1_Rulebase
    org.juzzy.server.ProcessInputs.<init>(ProcessInputs.java:26)
    org.juzzy.server.CreateFLS.doGet(CreateFLS.java:28)
    org.juzzy.server.CreateFLS.doPost(CreateFLS.java:39)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.
```

I have added the jar in the classpath as follows

[image: Classpath added]

The code does not show any error

[image: No error in code]

The class is present in the project

[image: Class present in Jar]

The jar is present inside the project and added to build path

[image: full project here]

Comment: which application server/server engine do you use?

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat 7 and Eclipse IDE

Comment: can you show the full structure of your project I cannot see where exactly you put your jar file

Comment: Edited my answer to show full project in last image.

Comment: please also show the full stacktrace

Comment: Add your library to web app libraries.

Comment: Showed stack trace @NicolasFilotto

Comment: @vzamanillo I followed instructions on the link you posted. Doesn't work for me. Still showing the same error.

Comment: is your `juzzy.jar` contains this

Comment: Yes it does. the type1.system is in juzzy.jar dropdown of my project